# flink: handling backpressure (source: kafka, sink: elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink job which is reading data from Kafka, performing certain aggregations and writing results to elasticsearch indexes. I am seeing High backpressure on the source. The high backpressure results in data being read slowly from Kafka, i see see data queued up in the network stack (netstat RecvQ shows tens of thousands of bytes of data stuck in the source kafka connections, the data is eventually read) which in turns causes the data to be sinked into elasticsearch after a lag and this lag keeps on increasing.

The source is producing ~17,500 records per minute, the Flink job assigns (event) timestamps to each incoming record, does 12 different types of keyBy, fits events in a 1 minute tumbling window, performs aggregation operations on this keyed windows stream and finally writes the results to 12 different elasticsearch indexes (each write is an insert).

The problem is that data being written to elasticsearch starts lagging so the dashboard results (built on top of elasticsearch) are no longer realtime. My understanding is that this is happening because of the backpressure build up. Not sure how to address this. The cluster itself is a VM based single node standalone cluster, with 64GB RAM (task manager is configured to use 20GB) and 16 vCPUs. There is no evidence (as seen from htop) of CPU or memory being constrained. There is only one task manager, and this is the only flink job on this cluster.

I am not sure if this problem is due to some local resource issue at the cluster or due to write to elasticsearch being slow. I have set the setBulkFlushMaxActions to 1 (as is done in all code examples i have seen anywhere), do i need to set setBulkFlushInterval and/or setBulkFlushMaxSizeinMB also?

I have gone through https://www.da-platform.com/flink-forward-berlin/resources/improving-throughput-and-latency-with-flinks-network-stack but have not yet tried tuning options listed on slide 19, not sure what values to set for those parameters.

Finally, i dont think i see the same issue when running the same job from within IntelliJ IDE.

I am going to exclude out all aggregations and then add them back one by one to see if there is a particular aggregation that triggers this issue?

Any specific pointers would be much appreciated, will also try the setBulkFlushInterval  and setBulkFlushMaxSizeinMB.

**Update 1, 01/29/2019**
Seems like both nodes are running at very high heap usage so the GC is constantly running trying to clear space in the JVM. Would be getting the physical memory increased from 16 to 32GB and then restart the nodes. That should hopefully resolve the proble, will know in another 24hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue got resolved by increasing (doubling) the RAM on the elasticearch cluster nodes and setting the index refresh interval (on all the elasticsearch indices) to 30s (default is 1s). After making these changes the backpressure in flink is reported as ok, there is no data lag and everything looks peachy.

Answer (score 2):

Typically in cases like this the problem is in the connection to the external data store -- either insufficient bandwidth, or synchronous writes for every record, rather than batching the writes.

One easy way to verify that the elasticsearch sink is the problem (rather than, say, the network stack config) would be to replace it with a discarding sink (one that simply does nothing), to see if this resolves the issue. Something like

```
public static class NullSink<OUT> implements SinkFunction<OUT> {
    @Override
    public void invoke(OUT value, Context context) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Update:

The problem is that you have set bulk.flush.max.actions to  1, preventing any buffering in the connection to the elasticsearch server.

Comment: ok seems like that was the problem. I did not use the NullSink but a similar idea, i removed the elasticsearch sink and just printed out the results to the console and that works perfectly. How do i ensure that the writes are batched? As you say "synchronous writes for every record, rather than batching the writes", how do i verify that? Do i need to set setBulkFlushMaxSizeinMB to a larger number (not sure what the default is)?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Elasticsearch sink, but I would experiment with the [bulk processor settings](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html#configuring-the-internal-bulk-processor).

Comment: By setting bulk.flush.max.actions to 1 you have effectively disabled buffering. This should be significantly larger.

Comment: i was thinking on the same lines, however setting the max actions to say 1000 does not help, i am still experimenting. Meanwhile i have also reached out to elasticsearch support asking them what should these values be set to. Will update as i find out more.

Comment: By default, every checkpoint will also cause a flush, and an acknowledgement, so aggressively frequent checkpointing will also cause frequent round-trips to the ES server.

Comment: checkpointing is not enabled (it was but i disabled it, as part of debugging).